# Enable Javascript function on image click

Tags: javascript, html

I had an image which appears on the click of another image.

I'm posting the code below. Please tell me where I went wrong. Thanks !

JavaScript

```
function suit1() {
  var element = document.getElementById("suit1");
  element.setAttribute("Hidden", "False");
}
```

HTML

```
<img src="suit1.png" style="width:100%; height:595px;" hidden="true" id="suit1"/> 
<img src="point.png"  onclick="javascript:suit1()">
```

Comment: Try with "Hidden" and "False" in lowercase.

Comment: Nope, It Didn't work.

Comment: Change `suit1()` to `suit()`. For some reason having  `1` in the function name is causing a problem. Also, change `element.setAttribute("Hidden", "False");` To `element.hidden=false;` Open your browser console, this will display errors.

Comment: It works fine with that function name fwiw.

Comment: shouldn't you use style?

Comment: @Andy When I run this with that function name it's showing an error in the console hence recommending a different name and a easier/short way of changing the attribute.

Comment: Thanks ! The number in suit1() was the problem :)

Comment: @epascarello you can use style but since `hidden` is an attribute you can access it as an attribute rather than a style. This post is using the attribute hidden  and not a style, I thought this would fit the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 function suit1() {
     var element =     document.getElementById("suit1");
  element.removeAttribute("hidden");
}
```

Comment: Nope, Even this does't work. The problem Im getting is not in the javascript. Its that the img is not executing anything onclick

Comment: Leave just word hidden in html as well <img src="suit1.png" style="width:100%; height:595px;" hidden id="suit1"/> 
<img src="point.png"  onclick="javascript:suit1()">

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, the number in `suit1()` was causing the issue. However, changing the function name to **any name other than the id for first img** resolves the problem. HTML:

```
<img src="suit1.png" style="width:100%; height:595px;" hidden="true" id="suit1"/> 
<img src="point.png"  onclick="javascript:some1()">
```

JavaScript:

```
function some1() {
  var element = document.getElementById("suit1");
  element.removeAttribute("hidden");
}
```

Or change the id of the `img`.